# Gratis, secure web browser which requires a password to open

Tags: windows, gratis, web-browser, security

Asking for a friend, who would prefer to use the [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/).

A plugin for that browser would be acceptable.

Failing that, a security oriented browser which requires a password at launch, otherwise it closes.

Additionally, the browser's data (bookmarks and history) must be encrypted on disk when not running

Must be gratis and run on Windows 10.

---

[Update] Thanks, @Thhomas for the comment.  I ought have said that I don't want a separate Windows user, as it too much trouble.

I was considering putting he portable version into a VeraCrypt container.

A program like WinGuardPro is also an option, with the downsides that it always running in background, and also the browser's data (bookmarks and history) may not be encrypted on disk when not running (I will add that as a requirement)

Comment: The Windows way to get this would probably be a new user account and then grant permissions for that account only. Running the program would require a logon with the credentials of the new account. You also don't want a more general solution like WinGuard Pro, I assume.

Comment: Oops! I should have said in the question that that is too much trouble. I was considering putting he portable version into a VeraCrypt container. A program like WinGuardPro is also an option, with the downside that it always running in background. Btw, the domain https://winguardpro.com/  is currently for sale (although I am sure that an old version would work. BUT, please see the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your friend suggests Tor Browser, i would recommend Tails.

[Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) is a Debian-based Linux distribution hardened for running Tor Browser. Bookmarks must be saved on persistent storage with a passphrase. (User could launch without a passphrase)

You could run Tails on Windows with [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). But the performance overhead would be quite large.